# Action torsion elements in the fundamental group of geometric orbifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, group-actions, orbifolds

In chapter 2 of *Three-dimensional Orbifolds and Cone-Manifolds*, theorem 2.26 states that

> complete geometric orbifolds $Q$ modeled on $(G,X)$, whith $X$ simply connected, are such that the holonomy representation $h:\pi_1^{orb}\to G$ is a isomorphism into a discrete subgroup $\Gamma<G$ which acts *properly discontinuously* on $X$.

Suppose $Q$ is a $2$-dimensional hyperbolic orbifold, i.e. modeled on $(Isom(\mathbb{H}^2),\mathbb{H}^2)$. I know that $\pi_1^{orb}(Q)$ may contain torsion elements, that hence are elliptic isometries of $\mathbb{H}^2$ and so have fixed points.

But eventually non-trivial elements acting properly discontinuously cannot fix any point by definition, so the question is, what am I missing/getting wrong?

I'm pretty sure that this is a stupid question, but I can't help to find my bug...

Comment: finite order elements can have fixed points and act properly discontinuously

Comment: Suppose x is fixed by g, how can it be satisfied that g(Ux)∩Ux? Or do I change the definition for torsion elements?

Comment: Just look at the definition of properly discontinuous. It allows finitely many $g$ forming a nonempty intersection.

Comment: Oh! Ok, thanks, apparently there are many different definitions for "properly discontinuous action" in literature (cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/properly-discontinuous-action) and I just appeard to have in mind a non-compatible one! thx

Comment: @Max: Your comments would make a good simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the definition of properly discontinuous action that one uses.
In literature are found many non-equivalent definitions (cf. [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/properly-discontinuous-action) on properly discontinuous action on mathoverflow).

In particular in this case the confusion arise from the fact that some authors require a properly discontinuous action of a group $G$ on a topological space $X$ to be such that every point $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood $U_x$ such that the only element $g\in G$ such that the property $g.U_x\cap U_x\neq\emptyset$ holds is the identity of $G$, while other authors allow that porperty to hold for finitely many elements.

The linked question discuss pros, cons, and relations between variuous definitions.